# oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036

Tags: oracle, oci8

I want to use simple oracle update statement with PHP from variable data on  Oracle database, but I am getting the error.

```
oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Part of the PHP script.

```
    $connection = oci_connect(getenv('DB_USERNAME'), getenv('DB_PASSWORD'), getenv('DB_HOST'), 'AL32UTF8');
    $sql = oci_parse($connection, "SELECT * FROM TG_EVENT WHERE
    result = 0
    AND regnum IS NOT NULL
    AND customer_id ='1872680'
    AND status_now IN (568, 569, 570)
    AND status_now != status_was");
    oci_execute($sql);
    
    $res = oci_fetch_all($sql, $rows, null, 1000, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
$update = oci_parse($connection, "UPDATE TG_EVENT SET result = '1'  WHERE customer_id = :customer_id");
oci_bind_by_name($update, ':cutomer_id', $result['CUSTOMER_ID']);
oci_bind_by_name($update, ':regnum', $result['REGNUM']);
oci_bind_by_name($update, ':status_now', $result['STATUS_NOW']);
oci_execute($update);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code

1- `oci_bind_by_name($update, ':cutomer_id', $result['CUSTOMER_ID']);` should be

```
oci_bind_by_name($update, ':customer_id', $result['CUSTOMER_ID']);
```

i.e you wrote :cutomer_id instead of :cu**s**tomer_id

2- `:regnum` and `:status_now` bind variables are not in your query, so remove them or change your query to add these bind variables